# Use 'conform' verbally in a sentence taking a direct object

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, direct-objects

Give me an example of a sentence using the verb 'conform' + direct object. I'm aware that this is usually used in a prepositional phrase however I'm wondering how it might be used without it. 
So give me a sentence using conform verbally without appending "to" (Datives are permissible).

Cheers.

Comment: Are you referring to a *transitive* usage of *conform* as in  :*to make the same or similar*: to conform one's idea to another's?

Comment: ... which is of the form conform DO to _NP_.

Comment: I'm using it transitively, yes. But it seems it's difficult to avoid using it reflexively.

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* finds two basic meanings of conform -- to make in accordance with and to become in accordance with.  The latter is used with the preposition "to," as in "I will conform **to** the dictates of the Church."  The former is **transitive** and can be *reflexive*:  "I will conform ***myself*** to the dictates of the Church."  Another example from the entry is from Richard Steele's daily *The Spectator* (1711-1712):  "Persons of every Party ... are fond of conforming **their Tastes** to yours."